# Hide your files in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i want to hide the css and js links in header and footer section in codeigniter

> > 
>
> ```
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
> ```

Comment: it's impossible ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the source CSS code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605396/hiding-the-source-css-code)

Answer (score 0):

When you write html code and include any resource, such as css or javascript files, they will be included on the page, but before doing so, a http request is made to download that resources. So hide any resource link is pretty impossible because, when someone visit the page must know which resources are needed and download it by the link.

So if you want hide those link for "users unaware", you can use some "trick", like disable right click from the page.